# What is the difference between Shell and ShellEx in Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, registry, shellexecute

I'm trying to add a custom context menu in windows registry, I found a shell key and shellex key that seems to both work the same thing? Why is there 2 and what are they for?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Shell` key is for [static verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx) used by `ShellExecute` and file-type context menus. They are simple to implement because they are just a string that specifies the command. They can be extended with optional COM objects (DropTarget etc.) if required.

The `ShellEx` key is for shell extensions, these are COM objects and there are various extension points in the shell and each type is a subkey of ShellEx. `ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers` is the shell extension version of the plain Shell key. The different types of shell extensions are [listed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468984(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Just follow up question, what would be a good scenario to use ShellEx over Shell key in general?

Comment: Explorer has a file selection limit of 100 for shell, unlimited for shellex. Shellex can also put icons and submenus in the menu on pre-Win7 versions. But shellex has more than just the menu, it also does propertysheet pages and other things, just read the page I linked to.