# managing right click context menus in window 10/11: Complete control over windows context menus

Tags: windows, dll, registry, contextmenu

#### Question

when you right-click on the desktop (or folder, file, etc) the context menu entries that appear are either statically generated or dynamically generated via a loaded DLL that implements [specific interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers?source=recommendations#implementing-shell-extension-handlers). read more about the differences between static entries and dynamic ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343562/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-and-shellex-in-windows-registry).

I just bought a new computer and decided to fully customize my windows context menu.
Basically, this question asks about complete control over your windows context menus, even the dynamic ones, and even the built-in ones(if possible).

The static entries are easy to manage and can be easily managed via the registry or a [tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185223/10577976).
the dynamically generated entries are the problem because it's hard to understand which of the loaded DLLs caused a certain entry label to apear.

**For example:** context menu on certain file types(like .txt) will load an entry "Move to OneDrive". how do I find the DLL that loaded that sentence?

so to summer up, how do i:

1. get from the context menu entry label(eg 'Move to OneDrive') the path of the ContextMenuHandlers DLL that loaded it. Alternatively, finding out the ContextMenuHandler that generated this entry.
2. ✅ <s>disable its loading.</s> (can be done by editing the UID to something else,for example prefixing with '-')
3. some values are restored after reboot, how do I cancel that?

('Move to OneDrive' is a true and annoying example but I asking about any entry, even the 'Rename' or 'Properties')

###### Possible directions:

Using Sysinternals [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) we can search a handle or a loaded DLL, however, how can you tell in a DLL generated a specific string(eg 'Move to OneDrive')?

#### Example:

*for documentation purposes, not actual part of the question*

Following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers?source=recommendations#example-of-an-extension-handler-registration) we can understand,

The registry entries that are responsible for the dynamic entries on the directory context menu are listed in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

let's take the EPP Key for example:

[image]

we can see that the value of the EPP key is `{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}`

following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers?source=recommendations#example-of-an-extension-handler-registration) example:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   .myp
      (Default) = MyProgram.1
   CLSID
      {00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444}
         InProcServer32
            (Default) = C:\MyDir\MyCommand.dll
            ThreadingModel = Apartment
      {11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555}
         InProcServer32
            (Default) = C:\MyDir\MyPropSheet.dll
            ThreadingModel = Apartment
   MyProgram.1
      (Default) = MyProgram Application
      Shellex
         ContextMenuHandler
            MyCommand
               (Default) = {00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444}
         PropertySheetHandlers
            MyPropSheet
               (Default) = {11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555}
```

using our value for the EPP entry `{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}`, we can understand that the DLL that loaded this entry is listed here   `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}\InprocServer32`, and in this case the value of this entry is `C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll`

[image]

We can 'Windows Defender' in the path, so we can assume it's responsible for loading the context entry with the label 'Scan with windows defender'

[image]

However, seems that that story does not end here, after disabling all static and dynamic entries for context directory there are still entries in the context menu. how do I revel which DLL loaded them?